# Pulling data from Stream Analytics to Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, iot, azure-stream-analytics, azure-machine-learning-service

Working on a IoT telemetry project that receives humidity and weather pollution data from different sites on the field. I will then apply Machine Learning on the collected data. I'm using Event Hubs and Stream Analytics. Is there a way of pulling the data to Azure Machine Learning without the hassle of writing an application to get it from Stream Analytics and push to AML web service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stream Analytics has a functionality called the “[Functions](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2015/12/10/azure-ml-now-available-as-a-function-in-azure-stream-analytics/)”. You can call any web service you’ve published using AML from within Stream Analytics and apply it within your Stream Analytics query. Check this [link for a tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-machine-learning-integration-tutorial/).
Example workflow in your case would be like the following;

- Telemetry arrives and reaches Stream Analytics
- Streaming Analytics (SA) calls the Machine Learning function to apply it on the data
- SA redirects it to the output accordingly, here you can use the PowerBI to create a predictions dashboards.

Another way would be using R, and here’s a good tutorial showing that https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2015/12/10/azure-ml-now-available-as-a-function-in-azure-stream-analytics/ . 
It is more work of course but can give you more control as you control the code.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

This is actually quite easy as it is well supported by ASA.
You can call custom AzureML function from your ASA query when you create this function from the portal.

See the following [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/stream-analytics-machine-learning-integration-tutorial/) on how to achieve something like this.